# How do I make my React app to open in Chrome browser by default?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am using **create-react-app** tool to develop React apps. The problem is that when I run the application using "npm start" command, it will open in Firefox browser and **I want it to open in Chrome browser by default.** 
I found many answers providing same solution which is about **modifying "start" in scripts section in package.json file** but I tried it over and over with different codes and it did not work. I have no idea why all answers I read did not solve my issue. **I am working in Windows 7.** 

This is my package.json code:

```
{
  "name": "jsx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
   "start": "cross-env PORT=8080 BROWSER='Chrome' react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

If I update "start" in script section in package.json, like this:

```
"start": "BROWSER='Chrome' react-scripts start"
```

It will not work and I get this error: 
**'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command**
and this is the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files 
  (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v11.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle jsx@0.1.0~prestart: jsx@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle jsx@0.1.0~start: jsx@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle jsx@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle jsx@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\KA\react\jsx\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Python36\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Windows\System32\Windows System Resource Manager\bin;C:\Windows\idmu\common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pandoc\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Users\KA\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;;C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad5;C:\Ruby22\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Users\KA\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe;C:\Users\KA\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\KA\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\KA\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\KA\.dotnet\tools
9 verbose lifecycle jsx@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\KA\react\jsx
10 silly lifecycle jsx@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', "BROWSER='Chrome' react-scripts start" ]
11 silly lifecycle jsx@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle jsx@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: jsx@0.1.0 start: `BROWSER='Chrome' react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:984:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
14 verbose pkgid jsx@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\KA\react\jsx
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v11.11.0
19 verbose npm  v6.7.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error jsx@0.1.0 start: `BROWSER='Chrome' react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the jsx@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Looks like you're close `"start": "BROWSER='Google Chrome' react-scripts start",`

Comment: I did this but it does not work and I updated the post so you can I understand the error I get in log file. @SterlingArcher

Answer (score 13):

Create a `.env.development` file in the project root directory, and include the following line:

```
BROWSER=chrome
```

Comment: Worked for me thank you. How do I swap `chrome` for the system default browser so the system picks it up on itself?

Comment: This opened on Chrome Canary for me, which was... exactly what I wanted! I only don't know why.

Comment: How to make it open in a particular chrome profile?

Answer (score 3):

In windows, set env variable:

```
set BROWSER=chrome
```

then just do `npm start` like normal

Answer (score 0):

Change your default browser to Chrome or use:

```
"start": "cross-env BROWSER='Google Chrome' react-scripts start",
```

Comment: I did this but it does not work and I updated the post so you can I understand the error I get in log file.

Comment: "Google Chrome" not just "Chrome"

Comment: I modified but still I get this error: **'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

Comment: Change your default browser to chrome, that's the easiest way out

Comment: @Tanaka I have edited the code. Add "cross-env" to your `package.json` and try again

Comment: I tried it but again this is the error: **'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command** - @Caleusdev

Comment: can you change the default browser to chrome?

Comment: `1- set BROWSER=chrome 
2- npm start`. These two commands work in cmd but not in script section.

Answer (score 0):

if your on wndows its

```
BROWSER=chrome npm start
```

Linux is

```
BROWSER=google-chrome npm start
```

MACOS Is

```
BROWSER=google chrome npm start
```

Comment: do you mean it should be like this `"start": "BROWSER=chrome npm start"` in package.json, in scripts seciton ?

Comment: this cant work on MACOS. what are you even doing here? this would set `BROWSER=google` in the environment and try to run the command `google` while passing it args `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Here you use two commands in one line, one of them is setting environment variable and another start node.js. 
Commands should be the following, in command line:

```
set BROWSER=chrome
npm start
```

Or you can set BROWSER env. variable in system envs, before run node.js

Comment: I tried but it says "Windows cannot find 'chrome'. Make sure you typed the name correctly". Then I tried "Google Chrome" , google chrome, "chrome", chrome.exe, and all these did not work.

Comment: without quotes?
**set BROWSER=chrome** - this correct record of env.

set BROWSER='chrome' - it's not work also for me.

Comment: Ah ok I tried again. It is working without quotes. I don't know what was the issue but before it worked, I found an option in Windows which gives you ability to set default programs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your windows settings and search for the default browser and set it according to your choice .... i was facing the same issue and resolved it by doing this...

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, your start script should include quotes around `google chrome`:

```
"start": "BROWSER='google chrome' react-scripts start"
```

Now `npm start` will open it in Chrome.

If you want the flexibility of using different browsers, add the following to your package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "chrome": "BROWSER='google chrome' react-scripts start",
    "safari": "BROWSER=safari react-scripts start"
}
```

These scripts work with
`npm run chrome` and
`npm run safari`

Answer (score 0):

Just run npm start
it opens normal browser if you want to open it in Chrome or in any other browser
just copy the URL and paste it into the desired browser

localhost:3000

in my case, this is the URL

Comment: That wasn’t OP's question. It was how to make the app open in chrome *by default*

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just directly remove `"last 1 firefox version", "last 1 safari version"` and let only `"last 1 chrome version",` stay in your package.json